# What does squared end spring mean?

Tags: springs, coil-spring

What does squared end spring mean?

In most cases I have seen shown closed and squared springs where the last coil touches the previous one.

But it seems that squared end means that the end is flat, but the end doesn't need to be closed. Is this correct?

For example this spring specification says squared and ground:
[image]
[image]

I'm confused, with what squared means.
Does it means just that the spring can stay upside?

Comment: wouldn't that depend on what the manufacturer means by the term?

Comment: [Understanding the Four Compression Spring End Types](https://www.jamesspring.com/news/compression-spring-end-types/#:~:text=In%20the%20open%2C%20ground%2Dended,the%20end%20coils%20to%20touch.)

Answer (score 1):

Squared means machined to match a flat surface perpendicular to the axis of the spring.

The other cheaper option, often found on car suspension, is to just make the mating surface have a surface designed to match the last turn of the spring.

Comment: Does it means that **ground ends**, **closed ends** or **closed and ground** would all be considered squared?